# Native typescript keyname object replacement

Tags: typescript

Im consuming a JSON from a web service, and the structure has all the keynames with a space between words.

Example:

```
"Payment": {
"seller name": "Seller Name",
"currency": "USD",
"pending amount": "400.78",
"total amount": "699.44"
 }
```

As you can see "seller name", "pending amount":, and "total amount" have spaces in it.  How can I transform those keynames for something like this:

"seller name" = "seller_name".

I have an array with 800 objects with the same condition, and I need to find a efficient way of doing this.

I tried this:

loadedData is the JSON from the ERP and mappedList is the List of objects with the correct format.

```
  let mappedReport: reportERP;

  for (let i = 0; i < this.loadedData; i++) {    
    mappedReport = {
      seller_name : this.loadedData[i]['seller name'],
      currency: this.loadedData[i]['currency'],
      pending_amount: this.loadedData[i]['pending amount'],
      total_amount: this.loadedData[i]['total amount']
    };      
    this.mappedList.push(mappedReport);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually a friend of mine was dealing with this situation too,
look at this solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/beautify-keynames
i just look for all the properties of my object and replace all the spaces (in this case) for that i just split it all and join it with underscore. Then if the value of the property is an object i call it recursively to call itself everytime an object value are found

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! very completed solution!

Answer (score 0):

This is a TypeScript example which replaces every whitespace character with an underscore:

```
const input = [{
    "seller name": "Seller Name",
    "currency": "USD",
    "pending amount": "400.78",
    "total amount": "699.44"
}];

const output = input.map((obj: any) =>
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce((acc: any, key) => {
        acc[key.replace(/\s/g, "_")] = obj[key];
        return acc;
    }, {})
);
```

Demo:

```js
const input = [{
    "seller name": "Seller Name",
    "currency": "USD",
    "pending amount": "400.78",
    "total amount": "699.44"
}];

const output = input.map(obj =>
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
        acc[key.replace(/\s/g, "_")] = obj[key];
        return acc;
    }, {})
);

console.log(output);
```

If you want to modify the original objects and not create a copy of the objects, you can use this snippet:

```
input.forEach((obj: any) => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(key => {
        const convertedKey = key.replace(/\s/g, "_");
        if (convertedKey !== key) {
            obj[convertedKey] = obj[key];
            delete obj[key];
        }
    });
});
```